# Limiting maxbytes for h5py files

Tags: python, limit, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to limit the maximum byte size (storage it takes on my pc) of an hdf5 file.

The number of datasets in my application is variable, I can choose to add or remove sensors from my test setup.The datatype coming from each sensor is also variable and contains different inputs (ints, floats, bools, etc.)

So I'm looking for a way to limit the size of the hdf5 file somehow. As requested I uploaded a severely simplified working example below. Any ideas would be much appreciated

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes
import h5py
import time

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ExampleA(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 8
    _fields_ = [('fUnderrange', ctypes.c_float),
                ('fOverrange', ctypes.c_float),
                ('bError', ctypes.c_bool),
                ('TXPDO', ctypes.c_int)]

class ExampleB(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 8
    _fields_ = [('bStatus', ctypes.c_bool),
                ('nValue', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('fValue2', ctypes.c_float)]

#Generating some random data, usually comes from sensors
#You can ignore this part for now
def generate_data():
    sample_A = ExampleA()
    sample_B = ExampleB()
    bytes_A = bytes()
    bytes_B = bytes()

    for i in range(10):
        sample_A.fUnderrange = np.random.random() #random float [0,1]
        sample_A.fOverrange = 1+5*np.random.random() #random float [1,6]
        sample_A.bError = 0 #No errors
        sample_A.TXPDO = np.random.randint(0,201)  #random int [0,200]
        bytes_A += sample_A

    for i in range(8):
        sample_B.bStatus = 1 #Status ok
        sample_B.nValue = np.random.randint(0,31) #random int [0,30]
        sample_B.fValue2 = 12+3*np.random.random() #random float between [12, 15]
        bytes_B += sample_B

    return bytes_A, bytes_B

#Converting the data to a numpy ndarray
#Have a look at what the data looks like using these variables
rawdata_A, rawdata_B = generate_data()
data_A = np.frombuffer(rawdata_A, dtype=ExampleA)
data_B = np.frombuffer(rawdata_B, dtype=ExampleB)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Create the hdf5 file
path = "..\\LogfileTest.h5"
d = {'sensor_A':data_A,
     'sensor_B':data_B}
maxrows = 10000

#Create the file and a dataset for each sensor
with h5py.File(path, 'w') as f:
    for name, data in d.items():
        dset = f.create_dataset(name, shape=data.shape, maxshape=(maxrows,), \
                                dtype=data.dtype, compression='gzip')
        dset.attrs['tracker'] = 0 #Keep track of where the last row of data was written

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Simulate a loop, getting new data each time
for i in range(30):
    time.sleep(0.1) #New data comes in every 0.1 seconds

    #Generate some random data
    rawdata_A, rawdata_B = generate_data()
    newdata_A = np.frombuffer(rawdata_A, dtype=ExampleA)
    newdata_B = np.frombuffer(rawdata_B, dtype=ExampleB)

    #Open the hdf5 file
    with h5py.File(path, 'r+') as f:

        #Write the data to the file
        for (name,data) in zip(d.keys(), [newdata_A, newdata_B]):

            #Open the correct dataset and check where the last line was written
            dset = f[name]
            tracker = dset.attrs['tracker']

            #Check if the data still fits in the file
            newsize = tracker + len(data)
            if newsize < dset.maxshape[0]:
                dset.resize((newsize,))

            #Write the new data after the tracker
            dset[tracker:tracker+len(data)] = data[:]

            # increment tracker
            dset.attrs['tracker'] += len(data)

            else:
                #Reset the tracker and start from the top of the file
                #I wont bore you with that code for now
                #But I'm looking for a system that checks the maximum size of the file
                #Instead of the maximum rows
                pass
```

Comment: What kind of data are you saving? integers, floats, strings?  I'm not quite sure what you mean by `byte size`.  [mcve]

Comment: What do you want to happen in the limit is exceeded? Could you subclass `h5py.File` and override the `write` method to keep track of how many bytes have been written, and then throw an exception if the limit is exceeded?

Comment: The data i'm storing comes from a range of sensors, its mostly bools, ints and floats. Im getting a few hundred variables every 0.1 seconds. When the limit is reached I want to start overwriting the oldest data. Im currently using a tracker, when the maxrow is reached I start writing from the top again.

Comment: Updated my question with a simplified example